# If there are 5000 ContentControl in WPF get created, the application turns into zombie process

Tags: zombie-process

If there are 5000 ContentControl in WPF get recreated each time when I click a button, the application turns into zombie process.

ContentControl are created by the DataTemplate. The memory usage keeps going up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e5350510-8a48-4c8f-9266-11ebd45e7497

There might be an memory leak there